# Simple java file reader not working

Tags: java

I am creating a program where two numbers are read from one file (*test.in*) and then the sum is output to another file (*test.out*). I created the two files as TXT documents in the *bin* folder of my project but it still gives this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.in.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(test.java:11)
```

The files are not showing up in my project directory on the left hand side of the screen, it just won't work.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.in.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.out.txt")));
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());    // first integer
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());    // second integer
        out.println(i1+i2);                           // output result
        out.close();                                  // close the output file
      }
}
```

Comment: If you are specifying just the file name they better be in the same location where your java program exists.

Comment: It doesn't actually work because I never closed the f input reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see your file is an textdocument, so it ends with ".txt" even if you can't see it in the folder!

You have to change "test.in" and "test.out" into "test.in.txt" and "test.out.txt"

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.in.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.out.txt")));
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());    // first integer
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());    // second integer
        out.println(i1+i2);                           // output result
        out.close();                                  // close the output file
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your files are ".txt" your strings "test.in" and "test.out" need to be renamed.
The other option is to change "test.in.txt" to "test.in" and
"test.out.txt" to "test.out".

Your files have to be from type "IN" and "OUT" **not** "TXT". As your **screenshot** shows they are **not**.
The fact that you are not seeing the suffix "txt" may be depending on your settings on your OS.

Your files also have to be in the same directory as your test.java file.

Comment: No. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your path and the filename. If "test.in" file is not in the folder that you invoked "java" command, it is normal to get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your files in the bin of the project is not the solution. The files are supposed to be in the root directory of your project. There might be some other issues like the name of your files; try to reference the files by their absolute path. E.g. `BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/MyProjetFolder/bin/test.in"));`.

If that doesn't work then the issue could be the extensions of the files. So check the metadata of your files to see if the extensions are as expected. If it's not, then rename the files to the extensions in the metadata (properties).

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to put the files in the bin folder. Put them in your project folder, the parent of bin/ and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a long time after I posted the question but I stumbled upon it and discovered that the real reason that it did not work is because the "f" input reader is never closed while the "out" output reader is closed. I simply had to add "f.close();" in order to make it work. It had nothing to do with the names of the text files, lol.

Here is the working code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.in.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.out.txt")));
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());    // first integer
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());    // second integer
        out.println(i1+i2); // output rresult
        f.close();
        out.close();     
        // close the output file
      }
}
```